# Prime numbers in the interval [2n, 3n]

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have to prove " If $n$ is even then $\displaystyle\prod_{n/2<p \leq 3n/4} p \cdot \prod_{n<p \leq 3n/2}{p} <  {\frac{3n}{2} \choose {n}}.  " $
However,  I can't find at least one prime numbers in $\displaystyle\prod_{n/2<p \leq 3n/4}p  $ when $ n= 2,6,14$. It is product of primes and if I can't find one it doesn't make sense if I will put  $ 0$ since $0$ is not a prime number and the left side of the inequality will be  $0$.My question is "What will I put there and why?  "

Comment: To summarise all the answers below: the empty product is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

One way to think of it is that
$$ \prod_{x:A(x)} x = 1 \cdot x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3 \cdots x_n $$
where $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots x_n$ are all the possible $x$ that have the property $A$.

If there are *no* $x$ such that $A(x)$, then all that is left on the right-hand side is $1$.

---

You can also think of it procedurally:

To compute $\prod_{x:A(x)} x$, start by writing $1$ down on a piece of paper. Then, for each $x$ such that $A(x)$, multiply the number on your paper by that $x$ and erase the old number. Then $\prod_{x:A(x)} x$ is the number that's left on your paper when you're done.

In each of these cases, it works fine if there is *nothing* that satisfies $A$; then the outcome is $1$. But neither of the views will work if there are *infinitely many* things that satisfy $A$; then we need to go to limits, and the *order* of those factors may become important.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: the product of no number is $1$.

If $A\subset \Bbb R$ is finite, we expect that
$$\prod_{x\in A}x=\prod_{x\in A}x\prod_{x\in\emptyset} x$$

Then, if $0\notin A$,
$$\prod_{x\in\emptyset} x=1$$
(Honestly, I'm not sure if this can be proved or must be defined).

Known examples are: $3^0=1$. $0!=1$.

Comment: I can't think of any more fundamental-looking definition it would follow from, so it has to be a definition. It can be _motivated_, but that's different.

Comment: @ajotatxe . I am confused. Can $x$ be an an element of empty set?

Comment: @jENEVA No, it can't. The product of the elements of the empty set is just the product of no number. The product of the primes in $(7,10.5]$ is also the product of no number.
---
Imagine that you are given a box that is supposed to contain some cards with numbers, and you are told to add them up. You open the box and find it empty. Your answer, and almost everybody's, would be "zero". But many people get confused if they are told to multiply them., The correct answer in this case is "one".

Comment: One way to look at why the answer is $1$ for no number is if you do the reverse. When you take away each number being multiplied, you divide the result by this number. As such, unless the value is $0$ at any point, removing the last value should give you $1$. This is, for example, how I've seen that $0! = 1$ is proven.